# unix_timestamp is not working in Laravel lumen framework

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

I am using **laravel lumen(7.x)** framework and facing an issue related to `unix_timestamp`
Please check the below query

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `contents` WHERE `date_added` BETWEEN unix_timestamp('2020-08-05 00:00:00') AND unix_timestamp('2020-08-05 23:59:59')";
$results = DB::select($query);
Output = 0
```

While running same query in `phpmyadmin`  output = 7

While running same query in laravel framework output = 7

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of `date_added` column?

Comment: date_added column datatype is varchar

Comment: Try ```WHERE `date_added` + 0 BETWEEN ...``` firstly... but this is not good idea to store numeric data in varchar column.

Comment: Same output I think this is beacuse of lumen framwork

Comment: In laravel it's working fine

Comment: Check actual query text received by MySQL in General Log...

Comment: I have changed the datatype to int still same issue . Is there any other way to solve this

Comment: why are you not using eloquent model ?

Comment: Don't you know that in laravel lumen we can't use eloquent model . it's a microframework

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$results = DB::selectRaw($query);
```

or

```
select(DB::raw($query));
```